# layout Button not visible

Tags: android, button, layout

I want to create the following layout for an `Adapter`of a list:

[image]

For this I have defined the following layout. But the problem I am facing is, that the Button is only visible in app landscapde mode. In the normal mode, I only see the text (covering almost the whole screen width) but I do not see the Button...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_origin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_destination"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/acceptRequestButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/accept"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with that design:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_origin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_destination"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/acceptRequestButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/accept"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have taken width of TextView as `match_parent` Change it to

> wrap_content

then it will work

Another solution which will definetely work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/acceptRequestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Accept"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/acceptRequestButton">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_origin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_destination"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: @faraz_ahmed_kamran Try this one it ll definitely work

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_origin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="text1"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="text2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/acceptRequestButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="accept"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code.

You have take the width and hieght of the textViews as match_parent.
This will make the button out of view.

Also you have give the width of the button fill_parent. You cannot do that.

I have used weights to equally distribute the two layouts.(LinearLayout and button). Tell me if you have any doubt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="2">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_origin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dummy text 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Dummy text 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/acceptRequestButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="accept" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try Vishal Puri code but change both LinearLayout height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

perfect working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="textview 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="textview 1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Button 1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```